# What does the confidence value mean on the output of sensors-detect?

Tags: temperature, sensors

Sample output of `sensors-detect` taken from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/lm_sensors#Setup):

```
Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Driver `lm90':
  * Bus `SMBus nForce2 adapter at 4d00'
    Busdriver `i2c_nforce2', I2C address 0x4c
    Chip `Winbond W83L771AWG/ASG' (confidence: 6)
```

What does this confidence value mean? If the confidence value is 6, does this mean the confidence interval is +/- 6°C?

Just curious as to how accurate the readings from `sensors` are. For me at least, these values tend to jump around a lot, and I was wondering if that reflects the actual fluctuating temperature of my CPU, or if it's just random noise.

Comment: confidence is how certain it is that the device is what it detected.  9 means it 99% sure it is that device and 1 is a wild guess.

Comment: Ahh, so it means the confidence that it got the device name / details right, not the confidence of the temperature readings themselves. If you turn this into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

confidence is how certain it is that the device is what it detected. 9 means it 99% sure it is that device and 1 is a wild guess.